# Why does this matlab function not divide?

Tags: matlab, division

The function below returns a value for mu that is always equal to "result" instead of the result of the division. Why am I missing for division to work properly?

```
 for k = 0:10
     result = func1(.95,k);
     plusone = func1(.95,(k+1));
     fprintf('plusone = %f  result = %f\n', plusone, result);
     mu = double(plusone)/double(result);
     fprintf('mu = %f\n', mu);
 end
```

The code for func, if it helps, is:

```
 function result = func1(c, k)

 exp = 2^k;

 result = c^exp;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no error. `mu` should always be equal to `result` because

```
plusone = c^(2^(k+1)) 
        = c^(2*(2^k))
        = (c^(2^k))^2
        = result^2

result^2/result = result
```

Comment: Unbelievable that I missed that. Thanks

Comment: Easy to miss error, @flapjackery. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue. Cheers.